# change attribute of appended element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html-table, row

```js
for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
  var tr = $("<tr></tr>")
  tr.append("<td>1</td>");
  tr.append("<td>2</td>");

  $("table tbody").append(tr)

}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tbody></tbody>
</table>
```

How Can I append rows and then dynamically change the rowspan of every second row. What I want to happend is it will look like below:

```html
<table border='1'>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td rowspan="2">1</td>
      <td>2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td rowspan="2">1</td>
      <td>2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td rowspan="2">1</td>
      <td>2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td rowspan="2">1</td>
      <td>2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td rowspan="2">1</td>
      <td>2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>2</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

I tried using index but it is not adding the rowspan

Any help is appreciated.

`FYI` : What I want to happened is append first then change the row span after the row is appended

Comment: what about selecting the rows as `tr:odd`? 
as you are giving the `rowspan` to odd rows only.

Comment: It seems you want more than changing the `rowspan`... Looking at your expected output it seems you want to : change the `rowspan` every odd lines AND remove the first `TD` of every even lines...

Answer (score 1):

Just added `mod (%)`

```js
for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
  var tr = $("<tr></tr>");
  if(i%2===0){
    tr.append("<td rowspan='2'>1</td>");
  }
  tr.append("<td>2</td>");
  $("table tbody").append(tr)
}
```

```css
td, th {
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  padding: 8px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
    <title>JS Bin</title>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <table>
        <tbody></tbody>
    </table>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: this is changing the attribute before appending. Like I said I want to append first then change attribute later

Answer (score 0):

I hope I achieve what you need.

I base the result from your second snippet.

```js
for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
  var tr = $("<tr></tr>")
  tr.append("<td>1</td>");
  tr.append("<td>2</td>");

  $("table tbody").append(tr)

}

$('button').click(function(){
$('table tr:odd td:first-child').remove();
 $('table tr:even td:first-child').attr('rowspan', 2);

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table border="1">
  <tbody></tbody>
</table>

<button>append</button>
```

Comment: I dont want another event for this scenario. What I want is append the tr after appending the tr then it will change the attribute. No click event

Comment: @guradio what about Jitendra Rangpariya answer? is it close?

Comment: close i think im still checking

Comment: @guradio ok just let me know, do you want to do the append while its looping?

Answer (score 0):

try to use html string and then attach it to your element and make the rowspan dynamic for example :

```
    var html_string = '<tr>'
    for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    html_string+= '<td rowspan="'+i+'">1</td>'
    html_string += '<td>2</td>'
   }
   html_string +='</tr>'
   $("table tbody").append(html_string)
```

Comment: this is changing the attribute before appending. Like I said I want to append first then change attribute later

Answer (score -1):

Below code may help,

```js
for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
  var tr = $("<tr></tr>");
  tr.append("<td>1</td>");
  tr.append("<td>2</td>");
  $("table tbody").append(tr)
}
$('table tr:odd td:first-child').remove();
$('table tr:even td:first-child').attr('rowspan', 2);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table border='1'>
  <tbody></tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: downvoter: Mention a comment if anything wrong in output?

Comment: I think your code is similar to the other answer, btw not the downvoter.